# Calling a web service from store procedure in Informix

Tags: web-services, informix

Is there a way to call a web service from a store procedure in Informix?

Or make a call to http?

Comment: By "call to HTTP", do you want to make a REST API call - GET, POST, etc.?

Comment: Your context isn't really clear.  What do you want to do with the information sent by the web service?  What format do you expect to use?  There are ways to do it, but it is not clear why you'd want to do it (you appear to have an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)).  Those ways to do it are not easy, nor necessarily sensible, but it is possible, especially if you write some C code for loading into the server, but that isn't something to be done casually either.

Answer (score 3):

From an Informix stored procedure, you can basically run any command line system commands. So if you want to make a REST API call, you can use the "cURL" command line tool/library. cURL is a standard package and available on most Linux distributions and macOS by default.

[Here is a nice article to help you get started in cURL](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-test-a-rest-api-from-command-line-with-curl/#11_What_is_curl)

Here is the [Informix documentation that shows you how you can use the SYSTEM command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1358.htm) to run any command line commands from within a SPL routine.